# Can I move between contiguous sequences of fields of the same type in a struct using pointer arithmetic without alignof?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memory-alignment, pointer-arithmetic

I *am aware* that there are other similar questions. I have read through these and don’t think this question has been answered.

Can I move between a consecutive (contiguous in the declaration sequence) sequence of fields of the same type of a struct using pointer arithmetic without consulting `_Alignof`?

I can move between array elements without consulting `_Alignof` because trailing padding is included.

However, is it possible that consecutive fields of the same type in a struct are not aligned the same way as in an array?

In other words, is it possible for this code to be undefined behavior?

```c
struct MyStruct {
    long int field_1;
    int field_2;
    int field_3;
};

int main(void) {
    struct MyStruct my_struct;
    int *field_2_ptr = &my_struct.field_2;
    int field_3_value = *(field_2_ptr + 1);
}
```

I *know* that this is bad practice. I *am* aware of `->`. I *know* padding can interfere in general. I want to know if padding can interfere in this specific circumstance.

This question is about C. I don’t care about C++.

So far I have compiled this with GCC and tried Valgrind to see if something is off, and compiled it with clang and UBSan. It seems to be fine, on this system (x86-64 Linux).

Comment: As dbush mentioned, this is UB but, here, it would _probably_ work. But, _whenever_ I see (e.g.) `int f0,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5;` I _always_ want to convert it to `int f[6];` as gulpr did. This usually results in better/faster code. As an example of such, see my answer: [How can I make this C code for checking checksum shorter?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236211/89044)

Comment: The other issue is that although your trick [probably] works, it is fragile [for future maintenance changes]. Some "idiot" [\*] programmer might _not_ see your `main` code and [reasonably] change the struct to: `int field_2; double xyz; int field_3;` This breaks the trick. Doing this might be hard to see and debug. So, we'd need a comment in the struct that points to the "main" code. But, doing that is a hacky, IMO. [*] Here, "idiot" is [lovingly] you [or me] in six months (when we've forgotten that we did the tricky code).

Comment: It might help for you to explain _why_ you have to (prefer to) use the solution you've come up with (vs. what gulpr did). Otherwise, this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/785231)

Comment: This isn’t an XY problem. I don’t have this problem in practice. I am genuinely asking this question, for curiosity’s sake.

Comment: Okay. With the aforementioned caveats in mind, the "abutting" trick will work _within_ a struct as (in practice) the struct forces the alignment/padding/ordering that makes the trick work. It _might_ work if the fields were globals but _no_ guarantees (i.e. UB). So, for pure _academic_ experimentation, well, okay [I've probably tried this before--40 years ago when I was learning C]. That said, it's important for you to understand _why_ you should never do this for _real_ code (for the reasons mentioned). As long as you get these points, enjoy ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is undefined behavior.

Pointer arithmetic is allowed on array objects (and single objects are treated as a 1-element array for this purpose) provided the original pointer and resulting pointer point to the same array object (or one element past the end).  Additionally, a pointer to one-past-the-end may not be dereferenced, otherwise it triggers undefined behavior.

This is spelled out in sections 6.5.6p7-8 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Additive operators:

> *7* For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the
> first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as
> its element type
>
> *8* When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
> from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
> pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
> is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
> original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
> resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
> In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an
> array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N
> (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and
> i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if
> the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
> expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
> and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
> object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
> object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
> of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
> object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined. **If the result points one past the last element
> of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*`
> operator that is evaluated.**

The section in bold is exactly what's happening here:

```
int field_3_value = *(field_2_ptr + 1);
```

Since this dereferences a pointer to one past the element of (essentially) a 1-element array, this triggers undefined behavior.  That `&my_struct.field_2 + 1 == &my_struct.field_3` would evaluate to true doesn't matter.

For the same reason, this is also undefined behavior:

```
int x[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int y = x[0][2];
```

While doing the above would *probably* work, there's no guarantee of that.  Modern compilers optimize aggressively, and they can and do assume no undefined behavior exists and exploit that assumption.

I've seen cases where, given pointers `a` and `b` which point to adjacent memory, `(uintptr_t)(a+1) == (uintptr_t)b` is true but `a+1 == b` is false.

Comment: Is dereferencing a pointer just past the last element of an array not UB? What is the result?

Comment: @schuelermine It is UB.  That's what the bolded quote from the standard says.

Comment: OK, I appear to have misunderstood

Comment: For completeness, consider adding the paragraph before the quoted one as well: _"For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves
the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its
element type."_ Since that's what applies to these struct members in the OP's code.

Comment: @Lundin Good call.  Added.

Answer (score 0):

As [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77852558/22907447) wrote it is a UB.

I would use an array to group members of the same type:

```
struct MyStruct {
    long int field_1;
    int fields[2];
};
```

and your code will not invoke a UB

```
int main(void) {
    struct MyStruct my_struct;
    int *field_2_ptr = my_struct.fields;
    int field_3_value = *(field_2_ptr + 1);

    /* or more simple */
    int field_3_value = my_struct.fields[1];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behavior was defined in the language the C Standard was chartered to describe, and the C Standard allows implementations to, as a form of "conforming language extension", support such constructs.  Clang and gcc will support such constructs when invoked with the `-fno-strict-alising` compiler flag, although they should not be expected to support such constructs otherwise.